# Tmux Wont Resize

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vi, tmux

This is my tmux.conf file

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

#chage prefix to control-a
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind C-a send prefix

#map Vi movement keys as pane movement keys
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R

#resize panes using prefix h,j,k,l
bind H resize-pane -L 5
bind b resize-pane -D 5
bind K resize-pane -U 5
bind L resize-pane -R 5

#reload .con
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"
```

The resize panes part is not working. It was working yesterday but weirdly stoped working today. I notices if I bind a key using a capital letter it wont work aswell, I dont know why. Any ideas whats causing this?

Comment: I see `bind b resize-pane -D 5` Is this a typo?

Comment: tmux remembers all configurations if atleast one instance is running. One solution that might work is to unbind everything using `unbind-key -a` and reloading the configuration again. More info here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57641/reload-of-tmux-config-not-unbinding-keys-bind-key-is-cumulative